# DELETE Query with LIKE Not Executing on All Rows

Tags: mysql

We're running a simple delete query on a Database with 25K rows. There are 50 rows that match this clause but it takes running the query twice to get rid of all of them:

```
DELETE FROM product WHERE brand LIKE 'Brand%'
```

Why doesn't this query delete all the rows that match in one execution?

[image]

Comment: can you please provide a [mre] when i run my delte all rows that fits get delete, you need to show the queries and the data

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `delete` from a `select`

```
DELETE FROM products 
    WHERE brand IN (
    SELECT brand FROM products 
    WHERE brand LIKE 'Brand%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting in batches.  You might have a hang up somewhere with foreign keys, or triggers delaying the deletion.

```
delete top (10) product WHERE brand LIKE 'Brand%'
while @@rowcount > 0
    begin
    delete top (10) product WHERE brand LIKE 'Brand%'
    end
```